# Passing variables in form between two articles in Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, forms, joomla, joomla-extensions

I am developing online form that would store values and passed them to another article which would display "results". I am using Sourcerer extension to blend simple counting JS script and php for passing variables into article. However, I know very little about Joomla and I do not know where to send variables. action=??? . I found tutorial on You Tube suggesting using article alias for this purpose however it does not work in 2.5.
If this is wrong approach towards solving this problem, could you please direct me.

```
<span id="remain"></span>
<form action="3.php" method="post" id="form1" name="form1">

<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Value1"> Value 1<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Value2"> Value 2<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Value3" checked> Value 3<br/>
<input type="submit" name="Go" value="submit">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=counter;
function counter()
{
seconds = 5;
countDown();
}   

function countDown(){
document.getElementById("remain").innerHTML=seconds;
setTimeout("countDown()",1000);
    if(seconds == 0)
        {
            document.form1.submit();
        }else {
        seconds--;      
        }
}

</script>
```

Link to the Youtube tutorial:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XgJmUo3BtrQ&feature=related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare something like this in your form action and fetch data on an specific article -

> index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=76 (your id of arcticle where you want to fetch data)

I hope this makes sense to you and let me know if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly advise against this only because it's quite contrary to the way Joomla is intended to work, so instead would recommend a Form extensions like Chronoforms, or similiar, which designed to do what you're apparently trying to do.  A complete list is at [Joomla Form Extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms)

Answer (score 0):

I'd also advise doing this in a different way but, if you continue down this path, your form action should be a URL. If this is to be the URL of another article, Joomla provides many different ways that URL could be structured. Probably the simplest is for you to use the Joomla administrator to create an 'article' type 'Menu Item'. Wherever you place this menu item in your menu structure will determine its URL. Then, use that URL for your form action.

But really, don't do it this way. Get an extension or even write your own, it's not very difficult to write Joomla components.

Comment: If I had few days spare, where would you advise me to start looking into writing Joomla components ?

Comment: http://docs.joomla.org/Category:Development  http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_(MVC)_Component_for_Joomla!2.5  http://docs.joomla.org/Component_Development  https://www.google.com/search?q=joomla+extension+development